# What tool was used to generate Vietnamese IPA entries on Wiktionary?

Tags: vietnamese

The IPA entries on en.wiktionary.org for Vietnamese words are very complete and surprisingly accurate. Moreover, every word has an entry for each of the three major dialects of Vietnamese. I would like to know what software tool was used to create these pronunciation entries. I have been searching for a complete rule set for Southern Vietnamese pronunciation, but thus far have not been successful in my quest. If there were a publicly available code base to extract the rules from, that would be really great.

Comment: What makes you think the entries are code-based? I seem to remember that there was quite detailed info in Elementary V by Binh Nhu Ngo - idk if you've looked there already. It was based on Ha Noi dialect but differences from Ho Chi Minh pronunciation were noted.

Comment: @rchivers Thanks for suggesting that book. I checked out the pronunciation section. Unfortunately, it only gives a cursory treatment of variations. There are many differences that aren't mentioned, like all the changes in finals and nuclei.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They use a template called [`{{vi-IPA}}`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Template:vi-IPA/documentation), which calls the module [`vi-pron`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Module:vi-pron). [Supposedly it's documented](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Module:vi-pron/documentation), but that page is empty, so the best we can do for now is look at [the code](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Module:vi-pron).

Basically, it breaks the text into syllables, then has lookup tables for initials (onsets), finals (nuclei plus codas), and tones, for each of the three major dialects. Each component of each syllable is looked up in the tables, and the results concatenated.

Comment: Note that if there's a minor detail not clear in the code, it's possible to look up who made that contribution with https://blame.toolforge.org/wikiblame.php?lang=en&project=wiktionary&article=Module%3Avi-pron and ask that user on their talk page